# How do I display my weather data in JSON format from Wolfram Mathematica API?

Tags: ios, json, output, wolfram-mathematica, weather-api

I am trying to display my weather data in a JSON format in order to use it in an iOS app (using swift in Xcode). This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"location" -> "Location"}, 
{temp : QuantityMagnitude[WeatherData[#location, "Temperature"]], 
hum : QuantityMagnitude[WeatherData[#location, "Humidity"]], 
windD : QuantityMagnitude[WeatherData[#location, "WindDirection"]], 
windS : QuantityMagnitude[WeatherData[#location, "WindSpeed"]]} &,
"JSON"], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This code produces the following output (after you put in "?location=Stellenbosch" at the end of the URL):

```
Failed to export to JSON for input:
{temp:21.4, hum:0.526, windD:320, windS:11.3}
```

But if I change the output to "Text" then it gives the following output (after giving it a location parameter):

```
temp:21.4
hum:0.526
windD:320
windS:11.3
```

How do I get the weather data in a JSON format?

Comment: I think the first thing you should try is to use Mathematica syntax for the arguments of Mathematica functions, that is use something like `"temp"->QuantityMagnitude[...]` instead of `temp: QuantityMagnitude[...]`. (Actually what you use is valid Mathematica syntax, but it means something very different than what it means when interpreted as JSON...)